# how to make php get request on android studio

Tags: java, php, android

**I want to make a notification on my app I made the PHP file correctly but facing a problem on the android studio I made the following android studio code but it's crashing the whole app what to do? here's my NotificationFragment**

...................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.classes.purchaselogic.JSONParser;

import battleworld.config.config;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class NotificationFragment extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    private final JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // url to get all products list
    private static final String url = config.mainurl + "get_all_noti.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_NID = "n_id";
    private static final String TAG_NSUB = "n_sub";
    private static final String TAG_NMSG = "n_msg";



    private int success;

    class OneLoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NotificationFragment.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(TAG_NID, "n_id");
            params.put(TAG_NSUB, "n_sub");
            params.put(TAG_NMSG, "n_msg");

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
//            Log.d("All Offers: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();

            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /*
                      Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     */
                    if (success == 1) {
                        // offers found
                        // Getting Array of offers

                        Toast.makeText(NotificationFragment.this,"Msg done Succsessfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } else if(success == 0){
                        // no offers found
                        Toast.makeText(NotificationFragment.this,"test!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(NotificationFragment.this,"we are facing some problem",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

**and heres my get_all_noti.php**

`````
/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 * All product details are read from HTTP POST Request
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_REQUEST['n_id']) && isset($_REQUEST['n_sub']) && isset($_REQUEST['n_msg'])) {

     $n_id= $_REQUEST['n_id'];
     $n_sub= $_REQUEST['n_sub'];
     $n_msg= $_REQUEST['n_msg'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/../db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();
    $conn = $db->connect();

    // POST all iid from users table
    $results = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM notification") or die(mysql_error());
        
        // check for empty result
        if (mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0) {
            // looping through all results
            // rajan node
            $response["rajanr"] = array();
            
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
                // temp user array
                //     $rajan = array();        
                //     $rajan["no"] = $row["no"];
                //     $rajan["date"] = $row["date"];
                //     $rajan["name"] = $row["name"];
                //     $rajan["url"] = $row["url"];
                //     $rajan["detail"] = $row["detail"];
                //  $rajan["category"] = $row["category"];
                //  $rajan["expire"] = $row["expire"];
                //  $rajan["view"] = $row["view"];
        
        
                // push single rajan into final response array
                array_push($response["rajanr"], $row);
            }
        
            // successfully inserted into database
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "noti get succsessfully done.";

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>````
`````

Comment: Please include the stack trace in the logcat window which should provide more info on "it's crashing the whole app".  Btw, `onPostExecute` already executes on the UI thread.

Comment: @A__ mm i found something.. its a fragment file i am doing it like  ```Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, NotificationFragment.class);
                startActivity(intent);``` how to make it like if I click on the image it will go to the fragment file this isn't working and saying have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: I followed [this](https://androidjson.com/android-server-login-registration-php-mysql/) tutorial and it worked for me.